# Первый опыт в node.js Можно ли не переделывая с нуля получить сносный результат?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, инспекция-кода, express, mongoose

Мой первый опыт программирования, если не считать студенческих лабораторных на Delphi(и те были очень давно).

Цель: "приложение" которое на первой странице выдает кликабельный список из имен юзеров(имена берем в mongodb), а при клике на юзера перебрасывает на другую страницу, где уже отображает(беря из базы) подробные сведения о выбранном юзере.
Основательно переписал, получил вот это.

Вопросы:

1. Общая структура более-менее адекватна? Дорабатывать имеющееся или же переделывать с нуля?
2. В модуле userModel я подключаюсь к базе данных. Там предусмотрена простейшая обработка ошибки в виде сообщения в консоль. Как бы мне сделать так, чтобы эта ошибка попадала в express и я мог вывести в браузере объект ошибки?

```js
//app.js:

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var router = require('./router/router');
app.use(router);
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000!\nDatabase on mlab.com');
});

//router.js:
var express = require('express');
GetFirstPage = require('../lib/GetPages').firstPage;
GetSecondPage = require('../lib/GetPages').secondPage;

var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', GetFirstPage);
router.get('/user?:id', GetSecondPage);
router.use(express.static('public'));
module.exports = router;
//userModel:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(require('../credentials').mongo, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log('Error database connection\n', err)
});


const userShema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  age: String,
  disciplines: String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userShema);

//GetPages.js:
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var _ = require('underscore');
const User = require('./exportFromDB').user;
const NamesList = require('./exportFromDB').namesList;

module.exports.firstPage = function(req, res) {
  Promise.all([
    NamesList(), readMainPage()
  ]).then(function(results) {
    const list = results[0].map(function(item) {
      return item.name
    })
    res.send(results[1]({
      'list': list
    }))
  })
}

module.exports.secondPage = function(req, res) {
  Promise.all([
    User(decodeURIComponent(req.query.id)), readSecondPage()
  ]).then(function(results) {
    res.send(results[1]({
      name: results[0][0].name,
      age: results[0][0].age,
      disciplines: results[0][0].disciplines
    }))
  })
}

function readMainPage() {
  const myFile = require('../lib/exportFile').mainPage;
  return myFile();
}

function templateMainPage(template) {
  res.send(template({
    'list': List
  }))
}

function readSecondPage() {
  const myFile = require('../lib/exportFile').secondPage;
  return myFile();
}
//ExportDB.js
userModel = require('./userModel');


module.exports.namesList = () => {
  return new Promise(function(resolved, rejected) {
    userModel.find({}, 'name -_id', function(err, data) {
      resolved(data)
    })
  })
}
module.exports.user = (url) => {
  return new Promise(function(resolved, rejected) {
    userModel.find({
      name: url
    }, function(err, data) {
      resolved(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: И тут же вопрос вдогонку. Этот код работал. Через несколько часов снова включаю компьютер, запускаю- не работает. Первая страница отображается, но при переходе на страницу отдельного юзера выдает ошибку. Проблема оказалась в том, что теперь в req.url у меня оказывается /favicon. Почему его не было, и вдруг появился, как так? Поправил добавлением app.get('favicon.ico' ...)

Comment: Рекомендую задать вопрос на https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Здесь был хороший комментарий, в котором было 95% нужной мне информации, зачем удалили?

Comment: Если вы про **ответ** (!= комментарий), то он стёрт автором, и из комментариев я не могу заключить, с чего вдруг.

Comment: Тогда такой вопрос: я что-то экспортирую способом с коллбеками, внутри коллбека я подключаю еще модуль и там еще коллбек- это никуда не годится, или приемлемо?

Comment: @Alex78191, [Политика относительно вопросов с инспекцией кода (code review)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/186999)

Comment: Я основательно все переделал. Создавать новый вопрос с тегом "инспекция кода", или как?

Comment: Измените лучше этот.

Comment: @sanmai Так это уже переделанный вариант

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так стандартно выглядит запрос страницы всех юзеров:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  users.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    res.locals.users = docs;
    res.render('list');
  };
};
```

А в шаблоне страницы списка - юзеры выводятся в цикле `each user in users`, где каждый обёртывается в ссылку с атрибутом такого вида `href="/users/#{user._id}"` (или какой-там у вас синтаксис шаблонизатора)

А запрос страниц отдельных юзеров - `app.get('/users/:id', ...`, и в его обработчике, в объекте запроса значением параметра `req.params.id` будет айдишник юзера в базе, по которому он легко и запрашивается -

```
app.get('/users/:id', function(req, res) {
  users.find({_id: req.params.id}, (err, result) => {
    res.locals.user = result;
    res.render('user');
  };
};
```

Шаблон страницы получил объект юзера - `user._id user.name user.age` и т.д.
Всего и делов - спасибо ТиДжею Каравайчуку (или как там его) за Express.

Comment: Это конечно хорошо, но мне хочется работу с базой вынести в отдельный модуль(-ли), но вот не получается организовать получение данных из модуля так, чтобы выглядело красиво.

Comment: У меня сейчас все упирается в то, что я не могу сделать так, чтобы модули, которые обращаются к базе, вызывались "красиво". Из-за асинхронности получается что нужно из вызывать с коллбеками или промисами...

Comment: Подскажите, где можно взглянуть на код простенького приложения с такой "архитектурой"?

Comment: Независимо от того, происходит ли это в главном файле или где-то еще, факт того, что app.get и app.use находятся внутри какой-то функции- это очень-очень плохо, или можно закрыть на это глаза?