# Еще раз про асинхронность и экспорт в Node.js для самых маленьких

Tags: javascript, node.js

В отдельном модуле происходит обращение к базе данных и получение результата. Экспортировать это добрые люди мне предложили либо с помощью коллбеков либо с помощью промисов. Возьмем коллбеки, подключая этот модуль результаты я получаю так:

```
users(function(result){
  // далее логика обработки полученных данных...
  console.log(result);
});
```

Все хорошо, результат передается, но он внутри функции. Как вытащить его наружу? Никак?

В чем задача-то: получить данные из базы, прочитать файл(асинхронно) и на основе этих данных сделать то, что нужно. Но возвращая через коллбеки, у меня не получается сделать так, чтобы оба результата были доступны в одной области видимости. У меня ощущение, что я не понимаю чего-то очень-очень простого...

Я запутался, я не знаю что делать, и уже начинаю подумывать, что программирование- "не мое" и надо забрасывать это самообразование

Comment: Используйте либо глобальные переменные, либо замыкания (в JavaScript область видимости вложенной функции включает в себя и переменные из родительской, замыкающей, функции, что продлевает им жизнь).

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: @Arhad Да я бы рад это все использовать. Но логика по которой переменная results передается из модуля users не позволяет этого сделать(по крайней мере я не вижу способа). Мне предложили второй способ, без коллбеков, с помощью промисов, но там в итоге все упирается в ту же проблему, экспортируя результат работы модуля, он оказывается  внутри функции и не получается вытащить его наружу.

Comment: вам стоит почитать про замыкания. вот например [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/38642/)

Comment: Я читал. И даже есть подозрение, что понял. Я понимаю так: если мы забудем про асинхронность. Как вытащить result наружу из users()? Объявить переменную перед users(), далее внутри, там где console.log присвоить этой переменной значение result. Но так как про асинхронность мы забыть не можем, то получается, как вы говорите pyramide of doom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Идея nodejs как раз в асинхронной работе. Если вы используете **callback** (хотя рекомендую все же разобраться с **promise**), обработка должна производится внутри функции.

Вот такой вариант

```
user(function (user) {
  // тут есть доступ только к user
  fs.readFile('/tmp/input', 'utf8', function (err, myFile) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    // тут есть доступ и к user и к myFile
    var output = ''; // формируем результат
    fs.writeFile('/tmp/output', output, 'utf8', function (err) {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Я уже плохо соображаю, но по-моему у меня по тому же принципу и было сделано. Получается что коллбек на коллбеке и коллбеком погоняет и все это в итоге абсолютно не читабельно. Если не сложно, посмотрите сюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677515/

Comment: да именно так. **callback** внутри **callback**. это даже носит специальное название - [Pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)). **promise** позволяют вам избежать подобного вида у вашего кода.